# Creating a Callback URL for Wordpress Woocommerce to update Order Status

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, callbacks

I want to create a Callback URL to update the order status when data in JSON format is POST to it.

Post Format Example:

```
"hash": "43745580XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"status_feed": [{
        "order_id": "123456",
        "awbno": "1348616939310",
        "pickupdate": "2017-11-27 19:00:00",
        "current_status_desc": "Out for Delivery",
        "current_status": "OOD",
        "from": "GURGAON",
        "to": "BAHARAICH",
        "status_time": "2017-12-09 13:41:00",
        "scans": [{
            "time": "2017-12-09 13:41:00",
            "status": "Out for delivery",
            "location": "Bahraich_Kotwali_D (Uttar Pradesh)"
        }, {
            "time": "2017-12-08 20:44:00",
            "status": "Asked for delay delivery on 2017-12-09",
            "location": "Bahraich_Kotwali_D (Uttar Pradesh)"
        }, {
            "time": "2017-12-08 13:51:00",
            "status": "Out for delivery",
            "location": "Bahraich_Kotwali_D (Uttar Pradesh)"
        }, {
            "time": "2017-12-04 22:04:00",
            "status": "Reattempt - As per NDR instructions",
            "location": "Bahraich_Kotwali_D (Uttar Pradesh)"
        }, {
            "time": "2017-12-02 11:06:00",
            "status": "Asked for delay delivery on 2017-12-03",
            "location": "Bahraich_Kotwali_D (Uttar Pradesh)"
        }, {
            "time": "2017-12-02 10:58:00",
            "status": "Out for delivery",
            "location": "Bahraich_Kotwali_D (Uttar Pradesh)"
        }]
    }
]
```

Kindly help me with this issue, i am unable to find the right path to do this. I simply need a URL e.g. http://yoursite.com/some-callback-url on which the data in JSON format is posted and order status is updated accordingly.

Comment: I think the better way to do this, is by using the woo Rest API, have a look to this example (Woocommerce api docs) for updating an order status :
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-an-order